# SQL replace function error while using it to replace one string

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have **event** table in which there are two fields named as *sport, event_name* .
This was values such as:

> {sport:"Athletic";   event_name:"Athletic 100 meter"}

What I want is to use **replace function** to replace the string in *event_name* that matches string in *sport*  with nothing.
so the final output will be such :

> {sport:"Athletic";   event_name:"100 meter"}

And I was also joined it with other table so only ID that are to be replace are also present in other table
so I used in this way in following code. But it should an error : "Expected item: < result-column > " . Thank you

```sql
SELECT
   ae.id ,
   ae.city AS event_city,
   ae.sport,
   REPLACE(ae.event,ae.sport,' ') AS event_name ,
FROM
   athlete_events ae
inner join
    players_personalinfo pp on
    pp.id=ae.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the table aliases:

```
SELECT ae.id AS event_id, ae.city AS event_city, ae.sport,
       REPLACE(ae.event, ae.sport, ' ') AS event_name ,
       ae.event
FROM athlete_events ae JOIN
     players_personalinfo pp
     ON pp.id = ae.id;
```

I would also advise you to trim the result:

```
     TRIM(REPLACE(ae.event, ae.sport, ' ')) AS event_name,
```

This will remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thank you, but it was only while I was asking questions. This problem is still not solved I don't know if it really doesn't want to replace or what. and I tried the trim function but then it said " Not a statement"

Answer (score 0):

The REPLACE function is case sensitive. Try to check the data to make sure that the capitalization of each is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but they are same there is no difference in captilization or any way. They both are of dtype : TEXT

Answer (score 0):

The prior answers work, but you need to modify one of the field names in your query. In your description, you mentioned the field name is "**event_name**", but in your query, you reference just "**event**" (ae.event).

Also, I'm a little surprised that an event_id would join to a player's profile id. Seems a bit odd.

At any rate, I confirmed this SQL works in both postgres and oracle databases...

```
    SELECT
       ae.id AS event_id,
       ae.city AS event_city,
       ae.sport,
       ae.event_name as event_name_original
       REPLACE(ae.event_name,ae.sport,' ') AS event_name_kinda_ugly,
       TRIM(REPLACE(ae.event_name,ae.sport,' ')) AS event_name_clean
    FROM
       athlete_events ae
    inner join
        players_personalinfo  pp on pp.id=ae.id
```

Comment: It seems it worked for me too in Postres but not in SQLite

Comment: Ah, didn't see the SQLite tag in the original, sorry. Not sure there, sorry.